Nuxt 3.13.2: nuxt generate build hydration completed but contains mismatches errors
I develop a website that runs with Nuxt 3.13.2, DaisyUI and TailwindCSS with bunch of nuxt modules, kindly please check the package.json details below:
{
  "name": "the-website",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate --modern",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxt/image": "^1.8.1",
    "@nuxtjs/google-fonts": "^3.2.0",
    "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^8.3.3",
    "@nuxtjs/seo": "^2.0.0-rc.15",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^6.12.0",
    "@vee-validate/nuxt": "^4.13.2",
    "@vee-validate/yup": "^4.13.2",
    "@vueuse/core": "^11.1.0",
    "@vueuse/nuxt": "^11.1.0",
    "nuxt": "^3.13.2",
    "nuxt-booster": "^3.1.5",
    "nuxt-icons": "^3.2.1",
    "nuxt-mail": "^5.0.1",
    "nuxt-marquee": "^1.0.4",
    "nuxt-snackbar": "^1.0.4",
    "sass": "^1.77.5",
    "vue": "^3.4.27",
    "vue-countup-v3": "^1.4.2",
    "vue-router": "^4.3.3",
    "yup": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@egoist/tailwindcss-icons": "^1.8.1",
    "@iconify/json": "^2.2.218",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.7",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.13",
    "daisyui": "^4.12.2",
    "nuxt-aos": "^1.2.5"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@4.4.1"
}

nuxt.config.ts:
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  $production: {
    devtools: { enabled: false },
  },

  ssr: true,
  devtools: { enabled: true },

  app: {
    head: {
      titleTemplate: '%s %separator WSoft Labs',
      meta: [
        {
          "name": "viewport",
          "content": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
        },
        {
          "charset": "utf-8"
        }
      ],
      link: [
        {
          rel: 'icon',
          href: '/favicon.ico'
        }
      ]
    }
  },

  runtimeConfig: {
    // apiSecret: '', // can be overridden by NUXT_API_SECRET environment variable
    public: {
      baseURL: process.env.NUXT_BASE_URL ?? 'http://localhost:3000',
      apiBase: process.env.NUXT_API_BASE ?? 'http://localhost:8000/api', // can be overridden by NUXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE environment variable
      apiUrl: process.env.NUXT_API_URL ?? 'http://localhost:8000',
    }
  },

  imports: {
    dirs: [
      // Scan top-level modules
      'composables',
      // ... or scan modules nested one level deep with a specific name and file extension
      'composables/*/index.{ts,js,mjs,mts}',
      // ... or scan all modules within given directory
      'composables/**',
      'utils/**'
    ]
  },

  components: [
    {
      path: './components',
      extensions: ['.vue'],
      pathPrefix: false
    }
  ],

  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
    'nuxt-snackbar',
    'nuxt-icons',
    'nuxt-marquee',
    '@vee-validate/nuxt',
    'nuxt-aos',
    '@nuxtjs/i18n',
    '@nuxtjs/seo',
    'nuxt-booster',
    '@nuxt/image',
    '@nuxtjs/google-fonts',
    '@vueuse/nuxt',
    [
      'nuxt-mail', {
        message: {
          to: process.env.NUXT_MAIL_TO,
        },
        smtp: {
          host: process.env.NUXT_MAIL_SMTP,
          port: process.env.NUXT_MAIL_PORT ?? 25,
          secure: process.env.NUXT_MAIL_SMTP_SECURE ?? false,
          auth: {
            user: process.env.NUXT_MAIL_USER,
            pass: process.env.NUXT_MAIL_PASSWORD,
          }
        },
      }
    ],
  ],

  build: {
    transpile: ['vue-countup-v3'],
  },

  tailwindcss: {
    cssPath: [
      '~/assets/scss/main.scss',
      {
        injectPosition: 'first'
      }
    ],
    configPath: 'tailwind.config',
    exposeConfig: {
      level: 2
    },
    config: {},
    viewer: true,
    editorSupport: true
  },

  css: [
    "@/assets/scss/main.scss",
  ],

  snackbar: {
    top: true,
    right: true,
    duration: 5000
  },

  veeValidate: {
    autoImports: true,
    componentNames: {
      Form: 'VeeForm',
      Field: 'VeeField',
      FieldArray: 'VeeFieldArray',
      ErrorMessage: 'VeeErrorMessage',
    },
  },

  i18n: {
    locales: [
      {
        code: 'en',
        language: 'en-US',
        name: 'English',
        file: 'en-US.js'
      },
      {
        code: 'kr',
        language: 'kr-KR',
        name: 'Korean',
        file: 'kr-KR.js'
      },
    ],
    defaultLocale: 'kr',
    lazy: true,
    langDir: 'lang',
    compilation: {
      strictMessage: false
    },
    detectBrowserLanguage: {
      useCookie: true,
      cookieKey: 'wsoftlabs_i18n_redirected',
      alwaysRedirect: true,
      fallbackLocale: 'en',
    },
  },

  booster: {
    detection: {
      performance: true,
      browserSupport: true,
      battery: true,
    },
    performanceMetrics: {
      timing: {
        fcp: 800,
        dcl: 1200
      }
    }
  },

  image: {
    screens: {
      default: 320,
      xxs: 480,
      xs: 576,
      sm: 768,
      md: 996,
      lg: 1200,
      xl: 1367,
      xxl: 1600,
      '4k': 1921
    },
    provider: "ipx",
    dir: "assets"
  },

  googleFonts: {
    families: {
      Poppins: {
        wght: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900],
        ital: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900],
      }
    },
    display: 'swap',
    prefetch: false,
    preconnect: false,
    preload: false,
    download: true,
    base64: true,
    overwriting: true,
  },

  compatibilityDate: '2024-10-14'
})

my issue is when I try to run it via dev server via yarn dev, it will not show a warning for hydration mismatches:

but when I do run yarn generate && yarn preview, it does show the said error:

with this current app.vue codebase:

Now, I did a workaround and trying to tweak ClientOnly component to move the wrap and include the NuxtLayout component

after then, I re-run yarn generate && yarn preview, the hydration error is gone but my images is now not working anymore.

but when I run the workaround with yarn dev, it has the same result as the first screenshot (no hydration mismatches warnings/errors).
I'm running a module called nuxt-image to optimize the images on load when uploaded to the server and nuxt-booster to boost the SEO-related things of the app.
here's my repo for further details and do some workaround about it, please do leave some comments/suggestions/guidance/help with the repo as a form of help will be much appreciated in order to improve the overall project and most importantly, myself.

There is no benefit of trying to get rid of the warning/errors by trying to generate the app. Focus on the main problem: finding out what causes the hydration mismatch. No need to wrap it inside of a client-only either, because this defeats the whole purpose of SSR as a whole. You can check this answer for a starting point. As a whole, try to comment out pieces of your code to narrow it down, that way you'll find out where the issue is coming from. Another alternative would be to do a comparison with JS on and JS off with your app.

@kissu i see, I try to finding out what causes the hydration mismatch via running it to local dev server using yarn dev, but there's no showing a warning regarding the said issue even I remove the <ClientOnly> component, it only shows when I do yarn generate && yarn preview. I have a reproduction link that needs to tweak in order to run and hope that you'll able to run it since I have no idea why it doesn't run properly even I switch to berry version of yarn:
https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/noelc10/wsl-website
https://codesandbox.io/p/github/noelc10/wsl-website/main?import=true

It's weird that it does not display it during dev but it might also be an issue with the hydration itself. If you expand the error after the generate, maybe it can help narrow down the issue already. Otherwise, give it a try by disabling JS on some parts of your app, there is an extension that can be toggled with a keypress combo too!

@kissu can you share that extension so that I can try it on my end?
I think I manage to resolve my hydration issue by tweaking the I18n config in nuxt.config.ts changing the fallbackLocale sub-props to ko(for Korean) under defaultBrowserLanguage props in I18n, since my default translation locale is set to korean, it makes the I18n flick on the fallback 1st before rendering the default locale in which it is set to en.

This is the one I use: https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/quick-javascript-switcher/geddoclleiomckbhadiaipdggiiccfje?hl=en
